# Select left in SQL doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have tryed many things, but I just cant workout why my left dosent work.

this dos not work, only give me 5 (5 post) blank lines

```
$sql = 'SELECT work_id, LEFT(job_art, 15) FROM rum where work_id = :work_id';
```

this works

```
$sql = 'SELECT work_id, job_art FROM rum where work_id = :work_id';
```

this dos not work (

```
$sql = 'SELECT LEFT(job_art, 15), work_id FROM rum where work_id = :work_id';
```

and my sql looks like this

```
$work_id = $_GET['work_id'];
    $job_art = $_GET['job_art'];
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);              
    $sql = 'SELECT work_id, LEFT(job_art, 15) FROM rum where work_id = :work_id';       
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':work_id', $work_id);
    $q->execute();  
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);          
    ?>  

   <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>

  <div class="liste"><p class="padding"><?php echo  htmlspecialchars($r['job_art'])?></p></div>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are actually printing out the results. Can you show that code?

Comment: What do you mean by 5 blank lines?  Can you add the job_art column to your query, and gives us a few rows of output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to read the columns by name (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`), but you haven't given a name to the result of `LEFT(job_art, 15)`, so attempting to access `$r['job_art']` won't contain anything.

To fix this, you'll need to alias the value of your expression.  Your new query should look like:

```
SELECT work_id, LEFT(job_art, 15) AS job_art FROM rum WHERE work_id = :work_id
```